# Autolayout: Height not variable despite "height >= constraint"

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, autolayout, nswindow

I have a very simple view setup in my App.
The Window contains a single View Controller which looks like this:

[image]

You can see that the `NSTextField` message view has a `height >= 150` constraint with a priority of `1000`.

All the other constraints are self-explanatory (let me know if they're not).

Now while I can resize the window horizontally, the height of the window remains fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSTextField` does not respect the constraint because (I think this is the cause) it only has one line. Use `NSTextView` to use multi-line editable input fields.

Using `NSTextView` is the solution.

Comment: You seem to be right. When I don't set a height constraint at all the text field grows as I enter multi-line text. However, setting the size constraint works, setting a `> =` constraint which should make the text field grow does not work. I think this is a bug in auto-layout

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the constraints *you* have imposed in Interface Builder, the resizing behaviour of `NSTextField` is also influenced the its *Content Hugging Priority* and its *Content Compression Resistance Priority*.

[image]

Your message text field is being prevented from resizing because its vertical *Content Hugging Priority* (the extent to which it resists being expanded) is probably set at `750`. Change this value to `200` and see if you have any more luck.